# Is it possible to position the leaf nodes one below the other instead of next to each other?

Tags: d3.js, orgchart

I use [d3-org-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-org-chart) and I wonder if it's possible to position the bottommost elements below each other instead of on the same level:

[image: current orgchart]

There are some [exposed variables](https://github.com/bumbeishvili/org-chart/blob/master/src/d3-org-chart.js#L24) that can be adjusted but I couldn't find a property that would do the job.

If this feature isn't build-in, would it be possible to achieve this via adding a function using vanilla d3.js? I would we very happy for hints or recommendations how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes draw the paths end of the svg and align leaf nodes to bottom of the svg